# Inverse transform word count vector to original document

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, countvectorizer

I am training a simple model for text classification (currently with scikit-learn). To transform my document samples into word count vectors using a vocabulary I use

`CountVectorizer(vocabulary=myDictionaryWords).fit_transform(myDocumentsAsArrays)`

from `sklearn.feature_extraction.text`.

This works great and I can subsequently train my classifier on this word count vectors as feature vectors. But what I don't know is how to inverse transform these word count vectors to the original documents. `CountVectorizer` indeed has a function `inverse_transform(X)` but this only gives you back the unique non-zero tokens.

As far as I know CountVectorizer doesn't have any implementation of a mapping back to the original documents.

Anyone know how I can restore the original sequences of tokens from their count-vectorized representation? Is there maybe a Tensorflow or any other module for this?

Comment: CountVectorizer will remove all the stop words from the document, and then will only take those words which satisfy the parameters specified like `analyzer`, `tokenizer`, `n_gram_range` etc. And it don't store that information, so no way you are getting the original documents back.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @VivekKumar. How have you solved this problem? My aim is to examine the false predictions to funnel back information to engineer features.

Comment: As @dhruvpathak descibed and I said, you cannot get back and doesnt make much sense. If you want to do that anyway, start by examining the parameters of CountVectorizer, which deletes or ignores specific words, and try stopping that.

Comment: It makes sense as soon as you want to complement your count vector with additional features as input for the classifier. Ideal would be if you could pass a pointer to the original document for every sample... But i guess this is more of a feature request than a question.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. If you want to add other features along with the output of CountVectorizer, you can stack the features horizontally to that. See [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) and its examples for that.

Comment: It's about figuring out what features to add. I want to look at the original input documents that have been classified incorrectly. This way I would hope to gain some insights into what is causing the classifier to fail so that I can prevent that with specific new features.

Comment: No sorry. Then you need to maintain the documents yourself. The index in the original document matches with the sample (row) index of output of CountVectorizer, if that helps.

Comment: Yes thanks. Then the next problem would be to somehow preserve the matching when I do sampling for dataset splitting. Or I do dataset splitting before vectorization. I think that would work! Will try it out. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: In most splitters in scikit-learn, you can get the index of splitted data (e.g. train and test indices) which will again match and can be used in the original data.

Comment: The dataset splitting will also be a problem. Because for the test data, all those words which were not learned or present in the training data will be removed by the CountVectorizer transform().

Comment: True. Will use StratifiedShuffleSplit now instead of the abstraction train_test_split. This way I can keep track of the indices and retrieve the original documents :)

Answer (score 5):

CountVectorizer is "lossy", i.e. for a document :
`This is the amazing string in amazing program` , it will only store counts of words in the  document (i.e. string -> 1, amazing ->2 etc), but loses the position information.
So by reversing it, you can create a document  having same words repeated same number of times, but their sequence in the document cannot be retraced.

Comment: Thanks @DhruvPathak. Any hint on how to solve this problem? Especially with regards to error analysis. I want to examine the erroneous predictions.